# Align plane to ground

Tags: axis

I'm sorry, I'm sure this is a very easy function, but I'm having a hell of a time.

I have a bunch of 2 and 3 poly planes that I need to align to the xy floor. As is, they are floating in space, with random rotations. I made a plane to align to, thinking that might be the easiest way, but I can't seem to get the rotation, it aligns origins, even though I have normal selected in the transform orientations.

[image]

Comment: OK. I downloaded the Mesh Align Plus addon, a free one, and it works like a charm. Looking forward to hearing how to do the old fashioned way though, it has to be a simple operation : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty and turn on face-snapping with influence on move and rotate before snapping it to your rotated plane(empty is aligned):
[image]

parent the rotated plane to the empty and finally set the rotation of the empty as 0, 0, 0 before clearing the parent-relation:
[image]

**explanation:** the problem with the snapping without the empty is that there are no object rotations in Edit Mode, but only single vertices and their locations. If your rotation in Object Mode is applied (0,0,0) or not represented in the Edit Mode transformation of your rotated plane, then there is no difference to align to an other object also having 0,0,0 rotation in Object Mode. Only the transformation of the of the new empty (0, 0, 0) to the normal of your plane allows to rotate the plane in relation to this newly formed difference.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing the first half without any luck. Inserting the empty object, parenting etc was not in my process.....appreciate the help!

Comment: as i found out reproducing the case, the problem with the snapping itselfe without the empty is that there are no object rotations in edit mode, but only single vertices and their locations. If your rotation in object mode is applied (0,0,0) or not represented in the edit mode transformation, there is no difference to align to an other object also having 0,0,0 rotation. Only the transformation of the of the (0, 0, 0) empty to the normal of your plane allows to rotate the plane in relation to this newly formed difference.